# Is it possible to get all list items using CAML-query?

Tags: caml-query, caml

I'm trying to retrieve items from all lists on current site collection.

Is it possible to do that using a CAML-query?

Comment: is it using client object model (javascript,CSOM) or  SSOM C# ?

Comment: Get all files in all folders and sub folders of a SharePoint document library recursively using CSOM https://gist.github.com/bassemfg/9443322f17f754354b1d47c469916118

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SPSiteDataQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx) to query multiple lists in same web.

[More here](https://sureshunakka87.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/spsitedataquery-share-point-example/)